# How to resolve dependencies for ng2-ckeditor

Tags: angular, npm

To verify this problem I created a new Angular project:

```
$ ng new cktest
installing ng
  create .editorconfig
  create README.md
```

I added some trivial html input to the app component and ran it with **ng serve** to make sure everything was working ok.  Then add the editor:

```
$ npm install ckeditor --save
cktest@0.0.0 /Users/me/WebstormProjects/cktest
└── ckeditor@4.6.2
```

next:

```
$ npm install ng2-ckeditor --save
cktest@0.0.0 /Users/me/WebstormProjects/cktest
└── ng2-ckeditor@1.1.6 

npm WARN ng2-ckeditor@1.1.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-ckeditor@1.1.6 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-ckeditor@1.1.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.1.0 but none was installed.
```

At this point I have in my **package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "ckeditor": "^4.6.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

So it seems like **ng2-ckeditor** is written to work with a much earlier version of **angular** than I have.   Is there any easy way to resolve this?

**UPDATE**: I have a temporary work-around.

I pulled down the source (git clone https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor.git) for ng2-ckeditor.  Reading the code I could not find any visible issue with Angular 4 vs Angular 2.  So the following steps work:

1. Copy the src directory in ng2-ckeditor project into my application in its own folder.  It is just a few .ts files.
2. Uninstall (npm uninstall) the ng2-ckeditor so it is no longer in the node_modules directory.  I think this is not necessary but it eliminates the possibility of something accidentally getting imported.
3. In the app.module.ts redo the import for CKEditorModule to reference the folder created in step 1.
4. Load ckeditor.js in index.html:

   <script src="../node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

I don't know why but it just doesn't work when you try to include it in the .angular-cli.json file.

Now ng2-ckeditor works with no issues I have seen so far.  When the source is updated in the npm repository I will go for that but for now I am coding.

**UPDATE:**

The ng2-ceditor 1.1.7 release fixes this problem.

Comment: Well you can try to open an issue on their github repo asking them to update, or use some other library that works with your version of angular. If you **REALLY** need this library you could also fork the repo, edit their package json to use the new dependencies, specify the github link to your forked repo in your main project and pray that I works(or also fix bugs that appear along the way, which you could then also use to open a pull request)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can see the dependencies of it - it is Angular 2 (previous version of Angular, Angular 3 does not exist). You can either use Angular 2 for while in your project and contact the code  maintainer of the ng2-ckeditor project with question when he is planning to upgrade.

https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/blob/master/package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^2.1.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^2.1.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.1.0",
  "@angular/core": "^2.1.0",
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 1):

i checked ckeditor on angular 2.4. it works fine. angular 2.4 in many cases == angular 4. just try to use editor

Comment: Even if the library works right now, there might be problems that are only revealed after some time. Besides that missing peer dependencies means that npm won't generate a shrinkwrap

Comment: @Riiverside When i try that I get a console log message: The resource from “http://localhost:4200/config.js?t=H0CF” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).  That may or may not have to do with the version compatibility because I don't know enough to tell.

Comment: Well that could mean anything, but it looks more like something that webpack-dev-server would produce. Not sure though, but I don't think that it's caused by this library. Chances are the library will work like a charm, but missing peer dependencies are something you shouldn't sit on for too long, because it might just get out of control and cause you a lot of problems.